# DES Algorithm with Python Crypto.Cipher Key -8 bits

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography, pycrypto, des

I'm trying to encrypt a string variable to understand DES Algorithm with Python Crypto.Chiper package. But I don't really understand why key length must be 8 bytes long. I searched everywhere and I saw DES algorithm key length is 56 bits. Why are they different?

Comment: The parity bits are the LSB of each byte. See : [DES Brute Force (academic)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67349826/1820553)

Answer (score 1):

As described e.g. [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_(cryptography)#Key_schedule), the key consists of 56bit + 8 parity bits. Since these usually aren't used in the encryption-process itself, they usually don't get mentioned (see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34199/purpose-of-des-parity-bits) for details). In fact the DES implementation in `Crypto.Cipher` explicitly states that [parity-bits are discarded](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des.html). So basically it's a relic of the olden days of crypto and a design-decision of the creators of the library.